# A standard way to have the `generate` method of the `GenerateMixin` only output the generated tokens

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I assume a widespread use case like Question Answering would ideally only need to output the generated tokens (essentially discarding the prompt tokens). Is there a standard way to achieve this?

We can use the `return_full_text=False` parameter in the pipeline object’s **call** method to achieve this. Is there a way to do it directly on the `generate` method of `GenerateMixin`??